# Create HTML elements from Array

Tags: javascript

How do I create HTML elements dynamically from an array?

For example, if I got an array `const data = ['123', '456', '789']` , and I wanna create a `p` tag of HTML for each value of the array. I've tried to use the `foreach` method but it's not working, anything I do it wrong so far? Below is the code:

```js
const ct = document.querySelector('.ct');
const data = ['123', '456', '789'];
const createNewElement =
  '<p>' +
  data.forEach((elm) => '<a>elm</a>') +
  '</p>';
  
ct.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', createNewElement);
```

```html
<div class="ct"></div>
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Is your script running before the DOM is loaded? `forEach()` doesn't return anything; maybe try `map()`. Also, your `<p>` tags are outside your loop, so you'll only get one, not one for each value in the array.

Comment: Use `map` and join them: `data.map((elm) => '<a>' + elm + '</a>').join('')`. `forEach` will not modify the array or print anything.

Comment: `elm` is also within your string, so it'll literally print `elm`, not the array value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## with just appendChild and createElement

Using all what you used and just using `appendChild` this one is easiest solution.

```js
let ct = document.querySelector(".ct");

const arr = [100,102,900];


arr.forEach(value=>{
  const currentElement = document.createElement("a");
  currentElement.innerHTML = value + "<br/>";
  ct.appendChild(currentElement);
})
```

```html
<p class="ct"></p>
```

## without any createElement but just with innerHTML

another way of doing is making a string of html and just inserting it into element where you want those elements

```js
let ct = document.querySelector(".ct");

const arr = [100,102,900];

let fullHTML = "";

arr.forEach(value=>{
    fullHTML += "<p>"+value+"</p>";  
})

ct.innerHTML = fullHTML;
```

```html
<div class="ct"></div>
```

Links for learning more about this

- [createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)
- [appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)
- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Answer (score 2):

Simply you can use map, but `map` is return new Array.
After that using `join` to return string.

```
const ct = document.querySelector('.ct');
const data = ['123', '456', '789'];
const createNewElement =
  '<p>' +
    data.map((elm) => '<a>' + elm + '</a>').join('') +
  '</p>';
  
ct.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', createNewElement);
```

Comment: You may want to add some links to MDN documentation for `map` and `insertAdjacentHTML`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Array.prototype.map` instead of `forEach`, the `map` method of an array returns a new array, allowing you to save it inside the `createNewElement` constant, while the `forEach` method on an array runs something on each element inside the array without returning a new array.

the `.join('')` method used at the end is to convert the array (`createNewElement`) into a string, joining each element in the array by no delimiters, (the default delimiter is the comma `,`).

[Read more about Array.prototype.map() method here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const ct = document.querySelector('.ct');
const data = ['123', '456', '789'];
const createNewElement = data.map((elm) => '<p><a>' + elm + '</a></p>') 
console.log(createNewElement)
ct.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', createNewElement.join(''));
```

```html
<div class="ct"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is accumulate in the createNewElement all sub-elements. For this, you can use the .reduce method:

```
const ct = document.querySelector('.ct');
const data = ['123', '456', '789'];
const createNewElement = data.reduce((allElements, elm) => allElements + '<p><a>' + elm + '</a></p>')

ct.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', createNewElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this to iterate over the array

```html
<div class="ct"></div>

 <script>
        const ct = document.querySelector('.ct');
        const data = ['123', '456', '789'];
        let createNewElement = "";

        for (let k = 0; k < data.length; k++) {

            createNewElement += '<p> <a>' + data[k] + ' </a> </p>';
        }

        ct.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', createNewElement);
 </script>
```